# CSRF token on a web page with multiple forms?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, csrf-token

When CSRF is enabled and a web page has multiple forms, will all the forms have the same csrf token or each form has a unique csrf token?

If this is framework dependent, then how does it work in the context of spring security?

Answer (score 1):

CSRF is not associated with form or something but to associated with each request.

Each individual request contains new csrf token.