# CSRF token value when same page is opened in two tabs on same machine?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, csrf-token

From my understanding, when CSRF is enabled on server side, the server creates a token (say token1) and injects it in to the `form` and saves the same in the cookie of the client browser.
When the client sends the `form` request to the server, it sends the csrf token (token1) from browser cookie and also send the same token as in the `form`. The server validates the request by checking that the token in cookie and the token in `form` match and then processes the request.

Now, if i open the same `form` in another tab, will the server generate another token (token2) and inject it in to the `form` and cookie. Then, **in the cookie,** `token1` will be overwritten by `token2`. So the submission of the form in first tab will not work in this case? But from experience i see that the submission of `form` in tab 1 still succeeds.

So can some one explain how it's succeeding in the above scenario??

Comment: slightly related Q - [CSRF Token and Second Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63931974/csrf-token-and-second-tab) but has no answers

Comment: another related Q - [CSRF token on a web page with multiple forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422918/csrf-token-on-a-web-page-with-multiple-forms)

Answer (score 3):

Since you have added the Spring Security tag, I will describe how Spring Security uses the Synchronizer Token Pattern to protect against CSRF attacks.

> the server creates a token (say token1) and injects it in to the form and saves the same in the cookie of the client browser.

That's not exactly what happens. The server will create a CSRF token (token1) and store that token in the HttpSession. The CSRF token (token1) is also be embedded in the form on the client side. The client is also given a Session ID (session-id1) which is stored in a cookie.

When the client submits the form, it sends token1 and session-id1. The server will then use session-id1 to look up the HttpSession and get the expected CSRF token for that session. It will compare the expected CSRF token to token1 and if the values do not match, the HTTP request will be rejected.

If you open the same form in another tab, the browser will still have access to the Session ID (session-id1). That form will get the same token (token1) that was associated with session-id1.

In the end, there is only one CSRF token (token1) that is used in both tabs.

You can find more information about protection against CSRF attacks in the [Spring Security reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#csrf).

Comment: Well thanks for bringing in HttpSession in to picture.

Comment: what happens when the user opens a different form in a new tab. I am thinking the same csrf token (token1) will be used for the second form too. I am thinking so because spring-security might not have a means to differentiate between the forms. I could be wrong if spring-security is identifying the forms based on the form name etc. If this is the case then a developer should take care of not using the same form name across different forms. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Eleftheria, will appreciate if you can comment on how multiple forms are handled, like described above. This is super important as security is critical.

Comment: requesting for the return of IronMan - this post seems to have a contradicting approach - `The server includes two tokens in the response. One token is sent as a cookie. The other is placed in a hidden form field. The tokens are generated randomly so that an adversary cannot guess the values.` [Introduction to CSRF](https://medium.com/@charithra/introduction-to-csrf-a329badfca49)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139184/how-are-csrf-tokens-stored-on-the-server-side-by-spring-security-or-tomcat