# How are CSRF tokens stored on the server side ( by spring security or tomcat)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session, spring-security, csrf

This question is not about how CSRF tokens works, but is rather about they are stored on the server side.
In short, CSRF tokens are generated by server and injected in to the web page/form. When the form is submitted the csrf token is extracted by the server and compared to the one saved on the server. So far so good.

From this earlier posting - [CSRF token value when same page is opened in two tabs on same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64423121/csrf-token-value-when-same-page-is-opened-in-two-tabs-on-same-machine)
Here's the excellent answer which explains that -

> The server will create a CSRF token (token1) and store that token in
> the HttpSession. The CSRF token (token1) is also be embedded in the
> form on the client side. The client is also given a Session ID
> (session-id1) which is stored in a cookie.
>
> When the client submits the form, it sends token1 and session-id1. The
> server will then use session-id1 to look up the HttpSession and get
> the expected CSRF token for that session. It will compare the expected
> CSRF token to token1 and if the values do not match, the HTTP request
> will be rejected.

and

> If you open the same form in another tab, the browser will still have
> access to the Session ID (session-id1). That form will get the same
> token (token1) that was associated with session-id1.
>
> In the end, there is only one CSRF token (token1) that is used in both
> tabs.

Bit more info can be found in the quoted [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#csrf), but it fails to explain the server side part.

---

The above leads to more questions -

If another form (form2) is opened by user in a different tab - then what CSRF token will it get, will it be same as that for the first form(form1) ?

To explore and unsderstand better, I want to know where and how the CSRF tokens are stored in the backend when using spring security (unlike Session Cookies which are generated by Servlet Container, I am assuming that CSRF tokens are generated by Spring Security module). Is there just one CSRF token per session, which is used accross every form and every tab or there are several CSRF tokens.

Please clarify as much as you can... every drop counts

Comment: this post seems to have a contradicting approach - `The server includes two tokens in the response. One token is sent as a cookie. The other is placed in a hidden form field. The tokens are generated randomly so that an adversary cannot guess the values.` [Introduction to CSRF](https://medium.com/@charithra/introduction-to-csrf-a329badfca49)

Comment: By default it is stored in the `HttpSession` which is why you only get 1 per browser session as the `HttpSession` is identified through a cookie (by default) which is shared across the whole browser session. You can change where it is stored if you like .

Comment: @M.Deinum, gr8 to hear from you. Could elaborate over an answer. So if multiple forms are  opened in different tabs - each of them gets the same CSRF token (token1) and the httpsession hold only one token (token1) no matter how many tabs and forms - is that right?

Comment: Each tab shares the same session cookie (as such is the nature of cookies) and thus they share the same session. So 1 token. However it could be that tab2 actually creates a new session invalidating the token used in the form on tab1.